# How to avoid inserting duplicate contacts(using email check) in salesforce using apex batch?

Tags: salesforce, batch-processing, duplicates, apex

I am trying to insert new contacts and leads in salesforce using external api call in apex batch. I am running once in a day and inserting 500 contacts or leads in salesfoce.
  But my batch file is inserting duplicate contacts with same email address. I want to skip contact or lead records to insert when same email id already exists with another record.

If I check email address using query for each record then the SOQL query limit will be a problem.

How I can avoid duplicate insert in contacts or lead in salesforce.

Thanks in Advance
Rajendra J.

Apex code:

request.setMethod('GET');
              request.setTimeout(120000);
              request.setEndpoint('http://api.nurturehq.com/contacts/many?nurture_id='+last_insert_id+'&limit=10&auth_token='+obj_authentication.nurture_authentication_key__c);
              request.setHeader('X-Api-Version',   '2.0');
              request.setHeader('X-Access-Id',     'APP_ID3MVG9A2kN3Bn17hvx6UytrOeZp67_J835ecdoZ5eJmyC_BQS227UFPVb5KgNJW7YpVd9oTA6sCJ19msqZQ9sY');
              request.setHeader('X-Access-Secret', 'SECRET_KEY4317178691269588217');
 JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());
           // system.debug('jsondataaaa'+parser);
           NurtureSingleton__c nurSingle = [SELECT nurture_last_insert_contact_id__c FROM NurtureSingleton__c limit 1];
            List listContacts = new List();
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {

```
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                while (parser.nextToken() != null) {

              if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT){

                  Contacts cnts = (Contacts)parser.readValueAs(Contacts.class);

                 first_name=cnts.first_name;
                 last_name=cnts.last_name;

                 if(String.isEmpty(first_name)) {
                     first_name='-';
                 }

                 if(String.isEmpty(last_name)) {
                     last_name='-';
                 }

                         listContacts.add(new Contact(FirstName = first_name , LastName = last_name,Email=cnts.email,Title=cnts.title,Birthdate=cnts.birthdate,Phone=cnts.phone,
                             MobilePhone=cnts.mobile,Fax=cnts.fax,Description=cnts.description,LeadSource=cnts.lead_source,MailingCity=cnts.city,MailingState=cnts.state,
                             MailingPostalCode = cnts.zip, MailingCountry = cnts.country,Department=cnts.department,Salutation=cnts.Salutation,
                             MailingStreet=cnts.address,Nurture_contact_id__c=cnts.id,AccountId=cnts.salesforce_account_id));

                             nurSingle.nurture_last_insert_contact_id__c = cnts.id;
                          //insert listContacts;

              }
             }
           }   

       }
       insert listContacts;
```

Answer (score 0):

you stated that
"But my batch file is inserting duplicate contacts with same email address."

Question here is , is it a duplicate or just the same email address?

You will need to compare the whole record or at least first name , last name email and phone
Enterprise businesses will have point of contact emails, meaning that Mr smith Mrs Yong and other can and will have an email like support@... or Info@..... and  customer-care@..
So a simple validation on Email can't work if you have already one person in the list but another lead comes up.

Imaging a hospital that got AandE@xyzhospital.com , now you are selling health / hygiene products and selling direct to doctors, you are already selling to 2 doctors there and a 3rd ( a new lead joins) but you can only reach them under AandE@xyzhospital.com , the new lead would  not be created as you only compare the email address